# Static files served by Apache but not by Nginx

Tags: php, apache, nginx

My PHP application static files are served all right when running Apache but they are denied access when running Nginx although both http servers use my own user (the one I log in my Linux machine with) as their user.

The issue therefore lies within the Nginx or php-fpm configuration.

Here is some of the `nginx.conf` content:

```
user  stephane;
worker_processes  1;
http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  gzip  on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  upstream php5-fpm-sock {
    server unix:/home/stephane/programs/install/php5-fpm.sock;
  }
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    charset utf-8;
    location / {
      root   html;
      index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri = 404;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /\. {
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
      deny all;
    }
  }
  include conf.d/*.conf;
  include sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Here is the Nginx virtual host configuration:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name dev.extrapack.group.com;
  root /home/stephane/dev/php/projects/Extrapack-Mon/public;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /home/stephane/programs/install/nginx/conf/sites-available/extrapack.group.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/stephane/programs/install/nginx/conf/sites-available/extrapack.group.com.key;

  location /simplesaml {
    index index.php;
    alias /usr/share/simplesaml/www;
    location ~ ^/simplesaml/(module\.php)(/.+)$ {
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^/simplesaml/(module\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/simplesaml/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
    }
  }

  location / {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS 'on'; # Make PHP-FPM aware that this vhost is HTTPs enabled
    fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
  }
}
```

And the Apache virtual host configuration (that works fine accessing all the static resources):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName dev.extrapack.group.com
DocumentRoot "/home/stephane/dev/php/projects/Extrapack-Mon/public"
<Directory "/home/stephane/dev/php/projects/Extrapack-Mon/public">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
AllowOverride All           
Require all granted                 
</Directory>                            
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: There are a couple of things you'd want to change in your config, notably the `location / {` block. Here, you shouldn't have the `fastcgi_pass` directive because you have a `try_files` directive. If it can't find it, it passes it to the php block. In any case, modify your `try_files` directive as follows: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;` Having the second `$uri/` tells it to recurse any directory that mathces. So if your assets are in subfolders, NGINX can find it. If this is left out, it will search in `root` for the file and not the subfolders.

Comment: I replaced the `try_files $uri /index.php?$args;` by the `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;` in the `location /` block and restarted the Nginx server but my user is still denied access to the static files. Removing the `fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;` made the php files unparsable and offered for download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `location /` with these two locations:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
  if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
    return 404;
  }
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
  fastcgi_param HTTPS 'on'; # Make PHP-FPM aware that this vhost is HTTPs enabled
  fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

The first location handles static files.

The second location handles `.php` files. Since it is a regexp-location (with `~`) it has precedence over the first location if it matches, so `.php`-files get executed.

Comment: I did as you said and indeed the static files are now accessible. But when requesting the application root I get a `502 Bad Gateway` and the error log shows: `[error] 7601#0: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: dev.extrapack.group.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "dev.extrapack.group.com"`

Comment: I then used my own configuration but kept your pattern `
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {` and it now works fine. The application is displayed with the static files. I wonder what in your configuration block was in the way. But you solved the issue.

Comment: I mixed up the `include` and the `fastcgi_pass`, corrected this. Glad that it works for you.